# I can't plot_model on model with pycaret

Tags: python, import, scipy, google-colaboratory, pycaret

`plot_model(best, plot="residuals")`

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 plot_model(best, plot="residuals")

14 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/signal/_signaltools.py in 
11 from scipy import linalg, fft as sp_fft
12 from scipy.fft._helper import _init_nd_shape_and_axes
---> 13 from scipy._lib._util import prod as _prod
14 import numpy as np
15 from scipy.special import lambertw

ImportError: cannot import name 'prod' from 'scipy._lib._util' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scipy/_lib/_util.py)

I'm trying to plot my pycaret model with this line of code yet I used !pip install --upgrade scipy pycaret and didn't fix the issue. Any help?

I'm using google colab by the way.

Tried to install the packages again.

> from pycaret.regression import *
>
> s = setup(df, target='target',
> session_id=1405, normalize=True, normalize_method = 'minmax')
>
> best = compare_models(sort ="RMSE", n_select=3)
>
> plot_model(best, plot="residuals")

Comment: Welcome to S/O! Please create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can debug what's wrong easier.

Answer (score 0):

**Restart Runtime:** After installing the packages again, restart the runtime:

Runtime > Restart runtime